# Append current form data to iframe

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, append

I want to append the current form data to the iframe and submit the form within iframe instead of original form. Below is code snippet

```
  <script> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imageSubmit").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     $("#wrapper iframe").remove();
     $("#wrapper").append("<iframe src=''>" + $("#imageForm").html()+"</iframe>");
     $("#wrapper iframe form").submit();
     $("#wrapper iframe").load(checkStatus);
    });
   });

   function checkStatus() {
    var status = $.parseJSON($("#wrapper iframe").html());
    if (status.success) {
     alert("File " + status.filename + " uploaded!");
    } else {
     alert("Fail!");
    }
   }
  </script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <form name="imageForm" id="imageForm" action="SOMETHING">
    <input type="file" id="imageInput" />
    <input type="submit" id="imageSubmit" />
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

however, insted of appending the current form HTML to iframe it is adding the decoded HTML(excuse me for this word) to iframe.
Here is iframe output i got:

```
    <iframe>
        &lt;input type="file" id="imageInput"&gt;
        &lt;input type="submit" id="imageSubmit"&gt; 
   </iframe>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Iframes are different than other DOM elements since they create another document within the window.

The other little trick is need wait for iframe to load so use `load` event of `iframe` to add content

to work with an iframe ( same domain only) , you need to use `contents()`. Within `contents()` there is a new tree including `document`,`html`, `head` and `body`

```
/* dummy src to avoid same domain restrictions in some browsers*/
var jsbinIframeSrc='http://jsbin.com/evoger/1';

var $iframe=$('<iframe src="'+jsbinIframeSrc+'" width="400px" height="300px"></iframe>'); 

$("#wrapper").append( $iframe);

var $form=$('#imageForm').on('submit', function(e){
    /* demo code to show that submit works when triggered inside iframe*/
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).replaceWith('Form was submitted');
})



$iframe.on('load', function(){
    /* unbind "load" so doesn't add form again when submitted*/
    $iframe.off('load');
     /* insert form in iframe body*/
    $(this).contents().find('body').html($form);
    $form.submit();

})
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/otobug/2/edit

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. 
I did in below way, works like champ:

```
var iframe = "<iframe name='frame' id='frame' style='visibility:hidden' onload='onFrameLoad();'></iframe>";
$('wrapper').append(iframe);
$('#form').attr('target','frame');

function onFrameLoad(cur_form_number) {
.
.
}
```